# How do i make JOIN when need to carried out first table column values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, join, left-join

I have two tables `rawtable` and `tradetable`

**rawtable**

```
rawid companyname uniqueID 
1      AAA-XA         9CV
2      BBB-DEMO       10K
3      CCC-XOXO       7D
```

**tradetable**

```
tradeid securityname CUSIP
1       AAACOMP      9CV
2       BBBCOMP      10K
```

Now what I need is `companyname` from `rawtable` is bit mixed so I need to have `securityname` from `tradetable` as companyname for that I used LEFT JOIN

```
declare DataSourceId = 3;
SELECT DISTINCT
    @DataSourceId,
    dbo.CleanText(tradetable.securityname)
FROM    tradetable 
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            companyname,
            uniqueID 
        FROM
            rawtable 
    ) rawtable ON tradetable.cusip =  rawtable. uniqueID
```

which will give me `names` from `tradetable` but here I will miss the new not matching names from `rawtable` but I want those name too but in select statement

if I use

```
declare DataSourceId = 3;
SELECT DISTINCT
        @DataSourceId,
        dbo.CleanText(rawtable.securityname) --instead of tradetable
```

then I will select wrong mixed name

So how can I solve this problem? or from somewhere else I need to carried out correct names as I want it like `tradetable` `securityname`

**OUTPUT I EXPECTED :**

**rawtable**

```
companyname uniqueID 
AAA-XA         9CV
BBB-DEMO       10K
CCC-XOXO       7D
```

**tradetable**

```
securityname CUSIP
AAACOMP      9CV
BBBCOMP      10K
```

I WANT A `securityname` i.e `companyname` in proper format for that i'm checking `uniqueID`
if it is matching then it will fetch `securityname` from `tradetable`

NOW

when there is an addition record in `rawtable` like `CCC_XOXO` is there it actual name might be `CCC` so for taking `CCC` i should have to take that `CCC` from where it is  present in 3rd table or is there any other way?

means i need to import that 3rd table also in my JOIN right?

Comment: I've read your question twice but I don't understand it.  Perhaps add some example output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to take the value from `tradetable` and if it doesn't exist, take it from `rawtable`? Like this ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a2f8/1))?

```
SELECT dbo.CleanText(COALESCE(t.securityname,r.companyname)) AS companyname,
    COALESCE(t.CUSIP,r.uniqueID) AS uniqueID
FROM rawtable r
LEFT OUTER JOIN tradetable t ON r.uniqueID = t.CUSIP
```

Output is:

```
COMPANYNAME     UNIQUEID
AAACOMP         CV
BBBCOMP         10K
CCC-XOXO        7D
```

Comment: +1, I think OP does want that but with `companyname` wrapped in dbo.CleanText(), as in original query.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Ok, I can wrap it. Glad you understood the question the same way.

Comment: I was writing similar answer. But, I think OP is going to surprise us both ;-)